# How to check number of containers for given node in Ambari?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

How to check number of containers for given node in Ambari? If it is not possible in Ambari, is there any command to list all the running/reserved nodes for a given node?

Comment: What do you mean by containers?

Comment: actually that's YARN terminology. YARN Resouce Manager launches containers on nodes. Container is an abstraction for resources (virtual cores and memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The following command return list of all the nodes in a cluster and also number of containers running on them:-

```
yarn node --list
```